# Is it possible to verify a given `block hash` is valid in a contract?

Tags: blockchain, hash, verify

Inside my contract, I want to verify a given `block hash` is valid or not.

```
block_hash_validation(string blockhash) returns (bool){
   ...//check()
   return true; || return false;
}
```

Q1: If yes, from `block hash` value could I also learn its block number?

Q2: Or should I provide block number as well `block_hash_validation(uint blockNumber, string blockhash)` to see that does the block number points to the correct `block hash`?

```
block_hash_validation(uint blockNumber, string blockhash) returns (bool) {
   if (block.blockhash(blockNumber) == blockhash)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**: I don't see an obvious way to do that without getting into a gas-expensive loopy process that won't scale. A web3 client would be better suited to searching for it *in my opinion*.

**Q2**: I would incline to this approach if it's necessary.

It looks like it should be bytes32 instead of string. According to this: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html it will return bytes32, so probablly better to compare to same type.

Notice the warning about the limited scope: hash of the given block - only works for *256 most recent blocks* excluding current.

It looks like you can reduce the if/else to a one-liner, so this looks right to me:

```
function block_hash_validation(uint blockNumber, bytes32 blockHash) 
    constant returns(bool isValid) 
{
    return (block.blockhash(blockNumber) == blockHash);
}
```

No time to test. No warranty :-)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is possible to prove that a hash existed more than 256 blocks ago, if you provide the block headers form that block on, but it starts getting pretty expensive.

Comment: Maybe, could we implement our own custom contract for storing hashes of past blocks? which may has to trigger in every block (using `ethereum alarm clock`) to push the newly generated hash.

Comment: Sounds mighty expensive to me. I'd be looking for a different way to solve the purpose of it. Hard to say what to suggest. I'm curious about the use-case.

Comment: Instead of defining `blockHash` as `bytes32`, I guess we need to define it as `string`, since byte format is stored as string for example: "0x... `b = web3.eth.getBlock(0).hash;  block_hash_validation(b, 0)"` this works when blockHash is defined as `string` @RobHitchens

Comment: There's a type conversion in the javascript API ... toHex() (also, fromAscii seems to work). You can convert "myStringVal" toHex. Then you'll have a bytes32 representation of a string to work with. My thinking is still that the blockHash is returns a bytes32, so that's what you would want to compare. Just my impression from reading the docs.

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/11914/4575 :( @RobHitchens